# set two defferent entity, use the composite item processor is possible?

Tags: spring, compositeitemwriter

first of all
i appology my english is not good

where are 3 tables, A and B and C

get table A in read part,

and manufacture data,

and return B entity and C entity in processor

finally set B entity and C entity

is above can be just one step?

or have to make 2 steps?

im beginner of batch develop, thank you for your help

is possible to set two different entity at the same time in spring batch

Comment: Hello, it can be done in one step. Please check the answer provided to a similiar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181694/multiple-writers-in-spring-batch-with-different-entities

Comment: thank you! similar question is also great!